# Windows 7 - 'make' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: windows, cmd, makefile

I have Windows 7 and tried to use the 'make' command but 'make' is not recognized as an internal or external command.

I did `Start -> cmd -> run -> make`, which outputs:

> 'make' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file.

Then I typed 'mingw32-make' instead of 'make' (`Start -> cmd -> run -> mingw32-make`) and I get the same output:

> 'mingw32-make' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file.

What shall I do next in order to fix this problem?

Comment: Have you changed the working directory to the folder of your application?  Open a cmd window and then use the `cd` command.

Comment: yes I've done that, I'm trying to run 'make' in the folder of the project

Comment: I use the 'npm install' command, In the output I get this error: make is not recognised

Comment: More details about the actual application and how you are starting it will help someone to help you.  Edit your question to add more information.

Comment: You know that `start >cmd >run >make` is not an actual sequence that you can do, don't you?

Comment: Yes, i don't use make in Windows 7, I tried to run the 'npm install' command for a specific package and I got that error. Then I noticed that the 'make' command is not at all recognized by the system

Comment: Have you actually installed [mingw32](http://www.mingw.org/)?

Comment: Well I downloaded and installed mingw-w64 on my computer but when I do: start->cmd-> mingw32-make or mingw64-make , the command is not recognized, so what shall I do?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Your problem is most likely that the shell does not know where to find your `make` program. If you want to use it from "anywhere", then you must do this, or else you will need to add the full path each time you want to call it, which is quite cumbersome. For instance:

```
"c:\program files\gnuwin32\bin\make.exe" option1=thisvalue option2=thatvalue
```

This is to be taken as an example, it used to look like something like this on XP, I can't say on W7. But [gnuwin32](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/) used to provide useful "linux-world" packages for Windows. Check details on your provider for make.

So to avoid entering the path, you can add the path to your `PATH` environment variable. You will [find this easily](http://www.google.fr/search?q=windows%207%20adding%20path%20environment%20variable).
To make sure it is registered by the OS, open a console (run `cmd.exe`) and entering `$PATH`  should give you a list of default pathes. Check that the location of your `make` program is there.

Comment: I donwloaded 'make-3.81.exe' from the following link : [link](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/downlinks/make.php). I executed the 'make-3.81.exe' and a new folder 'GnuWin32' was created under C:\Program Files (x86)\. Then in Windows 7 I did: Start -> cmd -> cd C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin -> make (typed 'make') and the command was recognized. Afterwards I editted the PATH environment variable as you told me and the problem was solved! The 'make' command is now recognized by the system. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Here homepage for [`Make`](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/make.htm). (huh, seems so old app).

Comment: this works, just need to download and run it and add the " C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin " to ur "PATH" in env variables and it works like a charm. Thanks.

Answer (score 50):

In Windows10, I solved this issue by adding `C:\MinGW\bin` to Path and then called it using `MinGW32-make` not `make`.

Comment: I was trying to install nio4r-2.2.0 gem and just copied the mingw32-make program and renamed it to make and then installed the gem just fine.

Comment: what path are you teklling here

Answer (score 38):

This is an old question, but none of the answers here provide enough context for a beginner to choose which one to pick.

### What is `make`?

`make` is a traditional Unix utility which reads a `Makefile` to decide what programs to run to reach a particular goal. Typically, that goal is to build a piece of software from a set of source files and libraries; but `make` is general enough to be used for various other tasks, too, like assembling a PDF from a collection of TeX source files, or retrieving the newest versions of each of a list of web pages.

Besides encapsulating the steps to reach an individual target, `make` reduces processing time by avoiding to re-execute steps which are already complete. It does this by comparing time stamps between dependencies; if A depends on B but A already exists and is newer than B, there is no need to `make A`. Of course, in order for this to work properly, the `Makefile` needs to document all such dependencies.

```
A: B
    commands to produce A from B
```

Notice that the indentation needs to consist of a literal tab character. This is a [common beginner mistake.](/questions/1739434/whats-wrong-with-this-makefile)

### Common Versions of `make`

The original `make` was rather pedestrian. Its lineage continues to this day into BSD `make`, from which `nmake` is derived. Roughly speaking, this version provides the `make` functionality defined by POSIX, with a few minor enhancements and variations.

GNU `make`, by contrast, [significantly extends](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Features.html) the formalism, to the point where a GNU `Makefile` is unlikely to work with other versions (or occasionally even older versions of GNU `make`). There is a convention to call such files `GNUmakefile` instead of `Makefile`, but this convention is widely ignored, especially on platforms like Linux where GNU `make` is the *de facto* standard `make`.

Telltale signs that a `Makefile` uses GNU `make` conventions are the use of `:=` instead of `=` for variable assignments (though this is not exclusively a GNU feature) and a plethora of functions like `$(shell ...)`, `$(foreach ...)`, `$(patsubst ...)` etc.

### So Which Do I Need?

Well, it really depends on what you are hoping to accomplish.

If the software you are hoping to build has a `vcproj` file or similar, you probably want to use that instead, and not try to use `make` at all.

In the general case, MinGW `make` is a Windows port of GNU `make` for Windows, It should generally cope with any `Makefile` you throw at it.

If you know the software was written to use `nmake` and you already have it installed, or it is easy for you to obtain, maybe go with that.

You should understand that if the software was not written for, or explicitly ported to, Windows, it is unlikely to compile without significant modifications. In this scenario, getting `make` to run is the least of your problems, and you will need a good understanding of the differences between the original platform and Windows to have a chance of pulling it off yourself.

In some more detail, if the `Makefile` contains Unix commands like `grep` or `curl` or `yacc` then your system needs to have those commands installed, too. But quite apart from that, C or C++ (or more generally, source code in any language) which was written for a different platform might simply not work - at all, or as expected (which is often worse) - on Windows.

Comment: Of course, the `vcproj` option requires that you have Visual Studio or a similar product. If you are reading this, you are obviously already a Microsoft victim, but maybe hesitate to dig yourself deeper into that particular hole.

Answer (score 16):

If you already have **MinGW** installed in Windows 7, just simply do the following:

1. Make another copy of `C:\MinGW\bin\mingw32-make.exe` file in the same folder.
2. Rename the file name from `mingw32-make.exe` to `make.exe`.
3. Run **make** command again.

Tested working in my laptop for above steps.

Comment: or maybe do the second step then add make to path (environment variable) then step 3

Answer (score 14):

1. First make sure you have MinGW installed.
2. From MinGW installation manager check if you have the `mingw32-make` package installed.
3. Check if you have added the MinGW bin folder to your PATH. type `PATH` in your command line and look for the folder. Or on windows 10 go to `Control Panel\System and Security\System --> Advanced system settings --> Environment Variables --> System Variables` find `Path` variable, select, `Edit` and check if it is there. If not just add it!
4. As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5181709/custom-commands-in-windows-command-prompt), create a new file in any of your PATH folders. For example create `mingwstartup.bat` in the MinGW bin folder. write the line `doskey make=mingw32-make.exe` inside, save and close it.
5. open Registry Editor by running `regedit`. As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17689152/is-there-a-way-to-run-vcvars32-bat-every-time-i-start-a-cmd) in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` or `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` go to `\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor` right click on the right panel `New --> Expandable String Value` and name it `AutoRun`. double click and enter the path to your .bat file as the Value data (e.g. `"C:\MinGW\bin\mingwstartup.bat"`) the result should look like this:

[image]

now every time you open a new terminal `make` command will run the `mingw32-make.exe`. I hope it helps.

**P.S.** If you don't want to see the commands of the `.bat` file to be printed out to the terminal put `@echo off` at the top of the batch file.

Comment: Yes, that finally works. Maybe it isn't great when you open `cmd` and every time see `doskey make=mingw32-make.exe` but in fact it is really nice trick.

Comment: @PiotrWasilewicz check the **P.S.**

Answer (score 10):

For window-10 resolved error- make' is not recognized as an internal or external command.

1. Download MinGW - Minimalist GNU for Windows from here https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/
2. install it
3. While installation mark all basic setup packages like shown in image [image]
4. Apply changes
   [image]
5. After completion of installation
   copy C:\MinGW\bin
   paste in system variable

Open MyComputer properties and follow as shown in image
[image]

You may also need to install this

1. https://sourceforge.net/projects/gnuwin32/

Comment: VirusTotal flagged this one https://www.virustotal.com/gui/file/aab27bd5547d35dc159288f3b5b8760f21b0cfec86e8f0032b49dd0410f232bc

Answer (score 3):

As other answers already suggested, you must have `MinGW` installed. The additional part is to add the following two folders to the `PATH` environment variable.

- C:\MinGW\bin
- C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin

Obviously, adjust the path based on where you installed MinGW. Also, dont forget to open a new command line terminal.

Answer (score 1):

'make' is a command for UNIX/Linux. Instead of it, use 'nmake' command in MS Windows. Or you'd better use an emulator like CYGWIN.

Comment: `nmake` is not a default command either - in Win 8.1 32 bit at least.

Comment: nmake is not recognised as well

Comment: You need to have visual studio installed to have nmake. Windows does not come with this program by default.

Comment: I have Visual Studio installed, but nmake is not recognized as a command.

Comment: use the developer command prompt, it will have the proper paths added to your command window

Comment: for me it was mingw32-make

Answer (score 0):

Search for make.exe using the search feature, when found, note down the absolute path to the file. You can do that by right-clicking on the filename in the search result and then properties, or open location folder (not sure of the exact wording, I'm not using an English locale).

When you open the command line console (cmd) instead of typing `make`, type the whole path and name, e.g. `C:\Windows\System32\java` (this is for java...).

Alternatively, if you don't want to provide the full path each time, then you have to possibilities:

- make `C:\Windows\System32\` the current working directory, using `cd` at cmd level.
- add `C:\Windows\System32\` to you PATH environment variable.

Refs:

- use full path: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff678296.aspx
- cd: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731237.aspx
- PATH: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490963.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I am using windows 8. I had the same problem. I added the path "C:\MinGW\bin" to system environment variable named 'path' then it worked. May be, you can try the same. Hope it'll help!

Answer (score -4):

try download & run [my bat code](https://github.com/2bon/1click2install/blob/master/scoop/make.bat)

======run 'cmd' as admin 2 use 'setx'=====
setx scoop "C:\Users%username%\scoop" /M

```
echo %scoop%

setx scoopApps "%scoop%\apps" /M

echo %scoopApps%

scoop install make
```

=======Phase 3: Create the makePath environment variable===

```
setx makePath "%scoopApps%/make" /M

echo %makePath%

setx makeBin "%makePath%/Bin" /M

echo %makeBin%

setx Path "%Path%;%makeBin%" /M


echo %Path%
```

Comment: This answer could use some clarification

Comment: Thanks @Gibolt , could u tell me what's unClear? We just need2 run it. What else do u need?

Comment: I'm not Gibolt, but it's unclear what `scoop` is or why one would want to install that when that's not the question. Several of the other variables here seem tangential or coincidental at best, and it's not evident whether this actually answers the question at the top of this page.

Answer (score -5):

use mingw32-make instead of cmake in windows

Comment: Why should this work? Can you provide an explanation?

Comment: `cmake` is a completely different tool.