# Error while creating new rails app, Failed to build gem native extension

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

When I create a new rails app using this command `$ rails new testapp`
this is what appears

```
       exist  vendor/assets/javascripts
   identical  vendor/assets/javascripts/.keep
       exist  vendor/assets/stylesheets
   identical  vendor/assets/stylesheets/.keep
         run  bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/
Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/
Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/
Resolving dependencies........
Using rake 11.3.0
Using i18n 0.7.0
Installing json 1.8.3 with native extensions

Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
creating Makefile

make "DESTDIR=" clean
'make' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

make "DESTDIR="
'make' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

make failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/json-1.8.3 for inspection.
Results logged to c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/extensions/x86-mingw32/2.1.0/json-1.8.3/gem_make.out
Using minitest 5.9.1
Using thread_safe 0.3.5
Using builder 3.2.2
Using erubis 2.7.0
Using mini_portile2 2.1.0
Using pkg-config 1.1.7
Using rack 1.6.4
Using mime-types-data 3.2016.0521
Using arel 6.0.3
Installing debug_inspector 0.0.2 with native extensions

Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
creating Makefile

make "DESTDIR=" clean
'make' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

make "DESTDIR="
'make' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

make failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/debug_inspector-0.0.2 for inspection.
Results logged to c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/extensions/x86-mingw32/2.1.0/debug_inspector-0.0.2/gem_make.out
Using bundler 1.12.5
Installing byebug 9.0.5 with native extensions

Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
creating Makefile

make "DESTDIR=" clean
'make' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

make "DESTDIR="
'make' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

make failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/byebug-9.0.5 for inspection.
Results logged to c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/extensions/x86-mingw32/2.1.0/byebug-9.0.5/gem_make.out
Using coffee-script-source 1.10.0
Using execjs 2.7.0
Using thor 0.19.1
Using concurrent-ruby 1.0.2
Using multi_json 1.12.1
Using sass 3.4.22
Using tilt 2.0.5
Using sqlite3 1.3.11
Using turbolinks-source 5.0.0
An error occurred while installing json (1.8.3), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install json -v '1.8.3'` succeeds before bundling.
```

When I tried what it said in the last line and ran `$ gem install json -v '1.8.3'` I got the same error

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing json:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
creating Makefile

make "DESTDIR=" clean
'make' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

make "DESTDIR="
'make' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

make failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/json-1.8.3 for inspection.
Results logged to c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/extensions/x86-mingw32/2.1.0/json-1.8.3/gem_make.out
```

I am new to rails so I don't know what this error means, Thanks in advance.

Comment: It means you need to install GNU Make. Which is a program for compiling and installing other programs. However I would consider using Vagrant to setup a virtual machine running some sort of linux or using Cloud9. Most tutorials assume you are using *nix (or at least a real Posix compliant OS) and setting Rails and all the supporting tools up on windows can be a drag.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is the following:

`'make' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

Which is a common situation, I recommend you read the answer to the same problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23723364/make-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operable-program-or/23734705)