# Cannot execute 'make' command even after adding it to PATH?

Tags: windows, batch-file, makefile, cmd, path

'Make' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

The above message is what I get when trying to run the make command from cmd.
I've already tried including the location of make.exe(via mingw) to the path environment variable, double checked to make sure there were no formatting errors, and made sure that the registry type of the path key was set to REG_EXPAND_SZ (which fixed the earlier problem I had with 'qmake').

Everything I tried has failed so far, if anyone can offer any further insight into my problem, that would be awesome!

The path of the make.exe is through C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin\make.exe

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['make' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file - Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23723364/make-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operable-program-or)

Comment: Run the `PATH` command and copy and paste the output of into your question.  Also provide us with the full path to the `make.exe` you're trying to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still a mystery to me why it won't work with the make command, but it will work with the mingw32-make just fine...