# 'cmd' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. atom editor

Tags: java, atom-editor

I am using atom and I installed the "script" package to run java directly, but every time I use Ctrl Shift B to run a java file it shows this error message:

> 'cmd' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable
>   program or batch file.

I did add the jdk to environment variable 'path'.

This is the code I am trying to run:

```
 package script;
    public class script {
        public static void main (String []args)
        {
            System.out.println ("Hello world");
        }
    }
```

What could be missing here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['make' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file - Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23723364/make-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operable-program-or)

Comment: This question has been asked so many times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to ensure c:\windows\system32 is still in your path.

You have probably ***set*** your path to the JDK, rather than ***appending*** the path to the JDK.

https://discuss.atom.io/t/cmd-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command/34704

You want *something* like:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.15063]
(c) 2017 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\user>echo %PATH%

C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wi
ndowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\PROGRA~1\Java\JDK18~2.0_1\bin

C:\Users\user>
```