# make' is not recognized as an internal or external command Windows 10 Anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda, webserver

I am trying to run a biostars page on my laptop. [Example](https://www.biostars.org/).

I am following the installation instructions on this [here](https://github.com/ialbert/biostar-central).

I have followed everything up until the line `make forum demo`

I get this error when I run this command.

```
'make' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I have looked for an answer and found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23723364/windows-7-make-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operabl).

The top answer in this question says that I might be missing options, but I am not sure about what these options are.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install mingw in your pc

following are the steps to install mingw in windows and start biostar server

1. install mingw-get-setup.exe
2. open C:\MinGW\bin\mingw-get.exe
3. install mingw32-make
4. coppy all contents from "C:\MinGW\bin" to the folder which has "makefile"
5. open cmd from your folder path
6. execute "mingw32-make forum demo" command in cmd