# Why does my attempt to add "make" to path not let me use make

Tags: windows-10, gnu-make

Using a very helpful thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23723364/windows-7-make-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operabl) and [these](https://www.architectryan.com/2018/03/17/add-to-the-path-on-windows-10/) steps, I added make to my path (as C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin\make.exe).When I call $Path this shows up. However when I try to run make S4_pyext in cmd.exe which I run from Anaconda3, I get an error

`'make' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

I thought I may have not added make to the path correctly so ran

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin\make.exe" S4_pyext
```

Instead which resulted in an error

`mkdir -p build A subdirectory or file -p already exists. Error occurred while processing: -p. A subdirectory or file build already exists. Error occurred while processing: build. make: *** [objdir] Error 1`
I can't seem to make heads or tails of this error message. Does anyone know what may be happening on either attempt?

Comment: You need to provide more information; at the least, which shell are you using.  Beyond that, maybe cut and paste your makefile as well.

Comment: This makefile is built to run on a POSIX system like Linux or MacOS.  The `-p` option to `mkdir` is a POSIX flag that says "make this directory if it doesn't exist, but don't fail if it already exists".  This makefile cannot be used on a Windows system.