# Lithuanian stemming algorithm

Tags: python, windows, makefile, jupyter-notebook, stemming

I've been trying to execute lithuanian snowball stemmer in Python. There is a github link where a guy shows how to integrate it using Python but I'm stuck at command !make. It throws this error:

!make

libstemmer/mkalgorithms.pl algorithms.mk libstemmer/modules.txt

process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, env perl C:\Users\Pc\Desktop\snowball\libstemmer\mkalgorithms.pl algorithms.mk libstemmer/modules.txt, ...) failed.
make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified.

GNUmakefile:66: algorithms.mk: No such file or directory
make: *** [GNUmakefile:181: algorithms.mk] Error 2

This is the github code: https://github.com/venclov/Lithuanian_snowball_stemmer_preprocessing

Comment: You seem to have a number of problems here. The fundamental one is probably assuming that this is going to work out of the box on Windows. I'm tempted to vote to close as too broad. The acute problem appears to be that you don't have Perl installed.

Comment: Perhaps see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/56312275/874188

Comment: Welcome on StackOverflow. Please take a look at the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and especially at [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)?